# NativeScript/Angular2 Telerik-UI RadListView issue displaying images from remote urls

Tags: angular, telerik-grid, nativescript, radlistview

I have 2 issues that I am trying to resolve with ListViewStaggeredLayout directive in RadListView.
1) I would like to use **loadMode="async"** in order to have smoother initial loading of images. This works nicely with ListViewLinearLayout, but not at all with ListViewStaggeredLayout. Without **loadMode="async"** the staggered layout images display, but initial loading is not smooth.
2) I want to display images from remote url's in this list view, and again linear layout works, but not staggered layout with 2 columns.
This question is a continuation of this [previously asked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408171/nativescript-telerik-ui-using-listviewstaggeredlayout-for-images-in-radlistview/40418663#40418663) where I received helpful info, but now I am pressing deeper into the app development.

Here is a portion of my HTML:

```
            <!-- pictures is an ObservableArray of objects like this: 
                 {"title": "Dried Meat with Spices", "author": "Nice to Meat You", "photo": "res://listview/layouts/paleo1.jpg", "category": "paleo"} -->
            <div *ngIf="isLinearActive && useLocalPhotos">
                <RadListView [items]="pictures">
                    <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <GridLayout (tap)="viewImage(item)">
                            <Image class="wall-cover" [src]="item.photo" stretch="aspectFill" loadMode="async"></Image>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </template>
                    <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="200"></ListViewLinearLayout>
                </RadListView>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!isLinearActive && useLocalPhotos">
                <RadListView [items]="pictures">
                    <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <GridLayout (tap)="viewImage(item)">
                            <Image class="wall-cover" [src]="item.photo" stretch="aspectFill"></Image>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </template>
                    <ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>
                </RadListView>
            </div>

            <!-- photosURL is an ObservableArray of objects like this used to reference remote url: 
                 {"photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/za3LhYb5Nzve0BcgVCIgAwL9ETcUEpOoZVdo9KNnqi_WsowVpOXXzC-L4s9ZcGAL080GVw3YWDLboDuoR3F8"} -->
            <div *ngIf="isLinearActive && !useLocalPhotos">
                <RadListView [items]="photosURL">
                    <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <GridLayout (tap)="viewImage(item)">
                            <Image class="wall-cover" [src]="item.photo" stretch="aspectFill" loadMode="async"></Image>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </template>
                    <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="200"></ListViewLinearLayout>
                </RadListView>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!isLinearActive && !useLocalPhotos">
                <RadListView [items]="photosURL">
                    <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <GridLayout (tap)="viewImage(item)">
                            <Image class="wall-cover" [src]="item.photo" stretch="aspectFill"></Image>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </template>
                    <ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>
                </RadListView>
            </div>
```

Here is the full [Github repo](https://github.com/kinggolf/staggered): I have only tested this on iOS simulator and iOS device - no Android testing.

How do I improve the performance of the RadListView ListViewStaggeredLayout and can I use it with remote images or do I need to save these images to local file system and reference from there? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to nativescript 2.4 https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-2.4-announcement. It fixes the slugish ui for this component. To upgrade:

First of all to upgrade is done is a couple steps:

1. npm install -g nativescript@latest
2. npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save 
   or
3. navigate to root of your app directory and do tns upgrade latest.

For Android:

1. tns platform remove android (back up assets as needed before)
2. tns platform add android

For iOS:

1. tns platform remove ios (back up assets as needed before)
2. tns platform add ios

Then you can type tns info and verify that everything says v2.4.x

Comment: Thanks for your input jessiPP. I had upgraded to tns-core-modules 2.4.0, but cli & platforms still on 2.3.0. I see cli version 2.4.0 on npm, but I had checked github, https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli, and it still shows 2.3.0 as latest, so this is confusing to me. Anyway I completed upgrade to 2.4.0 on all, however, I still have the same issues. ListViewStaggeredLayout directive still is not performing.  Thanks again for your time and input.

Comment: Further info found here on github: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/35